# Asynchronous UI Unittest with Espresso,IdlingResource fails with race condition

Tags: android, multithreading, unit-testing, asynchronous, android-espresso

I'm trying to convert some of my Robotium UnitTests to use Espresso and have a problem when updating the UI through the test. The test is for a fragment that is a form displaying data from an object. The fragment has a method '*BaseFragment.object_set(object)*', which will then update the UI components (with lots of *TextView.setText(object.getField())*).

When I run the following inside my test...

```
BaseFragment fragment = (BaseFragment) getFragment(activity);
fragment.object_set(object);
assertNotNull(fragment.object_get());
```

...I get the this exception...

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

When I run this instead...

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        BaseFragment fragment = (BaseFragment) getFragment(activity);
        fragment.object_set(object);
    }
});
sleep(500);
assertNotNull(fragment.object_get());
```

...the test succeeds. Without the *sleep()* it actually fails for a race condition.

So, my understanding is that sleep is bad form with Espresso, and that we're supposed to implement and register an Idling resource. I tried this one...

```
 sEspressoIdlingResource.setNotIdle();
 activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         BaseFragment fragment = (BaseFragment) getFragment(activity);
         fragment.object_set(object);
         sEspressoIdlingResource.setIdle();
     }
 });
```

...and when debugging **I can see that Espresso is actually waiting for that resource to release... it's only that this will still lead to a race condition, failing the test. It also looks like the UI isn't being updated until AFTER *activity.runOnUiThread()* has finished, so I think I'm just not getting the principle of which thread is which... can someone help and explain?**

Below some of the test code if it matters (the test below would fail due to the race condition)...

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyTest{

    ActivityTestRule<AMain> mActivityTestRule;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<AMain> setUp() {
        // other code here
        mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(AMain.class);
        return mActivityTestRule;
    }

    @Before
    public void before() {
        Espresso.registerIdlingResources(BaseTest.sEspressoIdlingResource);
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
       Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(BaseTest.sEspressoIdlingResource);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_1_showDetailsFragment() {
        // more code here for activity and object
        sEspressoIdlingResource.setNotIdle();
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                BaseFragment fragment = (BaseFragment) getFragment(activity);
                fragment.object_set(object);
                sEspressoIdlingResource.setIdle();
            }
        });
        assertNotNull(fragment.object_get());
        // more asserts here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You've probably answered this yourself by now, but i believe i had a similar problem, which was Espresso wasn't waiting for the :

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable{...})
```

code to finish before performing its actions.
(in my case):

```
onView(withId(R.id.where_city_search_input)).perform(typeText("Ch"));
```

From what I could tell espresso waits the main thread to be in an idle state before performing its actions. So if you:

1. Define a runnable:

   ```
   Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable{...};
   ```
2. Tell the Instrumentation to wait for this Runnable:

   ```
   InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().waitForIdle(myRunnable);
   ```

Then run whatever Espresso code you want you should be good. In the end it should look something like this:

```
// Define Runnable:
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // What you want to run //
    }
};
// Run on UI Thread:
activity.runOnUiThread(myRunnable);
// Tell Instrumentation to wait:
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().waitForIdle(myRunnable);

// BEGIN ESPRESSO CODE //
    ................
// END ESPRESSO CODE //
```

Comment: Is there a way with espresso to the exact opposite? 

For me espresso is waiting for the Async task to finish which actually will take a very long time. I need espresso to not consider this thread and keep navigating through the application.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you don't know when the UI thread would run.

So you are doing:

```
fragment.object_set(object);
```

and

```
fragment.object_get()
```

on different threads.
If you want to update the UI you need to wait for it to finish. Fortunately InstrumentationRegistry has a method that does exactly this - **InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(Runnable)**

As the documentation points out:

> Execute a call on the application's main thread, blocking until it is
>   complete.  Useful for doing things that are not thread-safe, such as
>   looking at or modifying the view hierarchy.

So now if you need to validate a state after a UI update you can do the following:

```
Runnable r = () -> fragment.object_set(object);
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(r);

//assertions
fragment.object_get()
```